# XML parsing failed

Tags: oracle, xml

I'm using a query on a oracle db which extracts values from clobs using the xmltype function and an xpath. Unfortunately the query fails and reports a 'XML Parsing failed'. I assume that one of the strings in the clob is not a valid XML. How to determine which row is affected?